# IOS/Objective-C: Detect if jsonResults contain a key value pair

Tags: ios, json, null

In some situations, a JSON object I am trying to parse contains a certain key.  In other cases, it does not.

When I try to access a key value pair of the object whether the key does not exist, it naturally causes a crash.  Accordingly, I am trying to test beforehand whether the key exists.  However, an NSNull class test is not working for some reason.  Can someone suggest the right test to use to detect if a key is or is not present?

Here is my editied code to screen out null cases that it is not working:

```
NSDictionary *jsonResults = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
         NSLog(@"Results of post: %@", jsonResults);

 if ([jsonResults[@"response"][@"insert_id"]isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){
                    NSLog(@"insert id is null");}
else {
//EVEN WHEN I KNOW THAT THERE IS no insert_id key, I get to this code suggesting test above not working
    //Access insert_id value using Key value and so something with it
NSInteger insertID = [jsonResults[@"response"][@"insert_id"] integerValue];
    }
```

Comment: what does the crash say ?

Comment: __NSCFString objectForKeyedSubstrict:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: looks like  jsonResults[@"response"] is a string but not a dictionary!

Comment: I edited the question to show earlier NSJSONSerialization.  The results log to:{
    code = 200;
    error = "0(NSNull)";
    response = "edit -not insert";
}

Comment: as you can see, response is a string, but not a dictionary, hence jsonResults[@"response"][@"insert_id"] crashes.

Comment: what is correct syntax

Comment: first check if jsonResults[@"response"] is kindOFClass NSString or not, if not, then you can access jsonResults[@"response"][@"insert_id"]

Comment: jsonResults[@"response"] is a string.  However, jsonResults, as far as I can tell, is a dictionary.  What is syntax to test if there is a key in the dictionary with a certain key name?

Comment: jsonResults[@"response"] is same as [jsonResults objectForKey:@"response"] this returns nil if there is no key ;response'

Comment: is there syntax to go one deeper.  Let's say Response had several values such as {
    code = 200;
    error = "0(NSNull)";
    response =     {
        insert_id = 563;
        success = 1;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end it is an NSDictionary, if you research whether NSDictionary contains a key you will find more help.

`objectForKey`     will return nil if a key doesn't exist. 
You can try with:

```
if ([jsonResults objectForKey:@"response"] valueForKey:@"insert_id"] != nil {
    NSLog(@"insert id is not null");
}
```

or to be sure that your response is a dictionary

```
NSDictionary *response = jsonResults[@"response"];
if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
   if (jsonResults[@"response"][@"insert_id"] != nil {
    NSLog(@"insert id is not null");
   }
}
```